# Displaying currency in gridview

Tags: asp.net

i was wondering whether there would be anyway to format the grid view control that would display the pound symbol before the values. In the access database, there is a currency symbol, however, when attaching the database to the grid view, the data shows but without the currency symbol.

Sorry for a poorly written description of my problem. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try using DataFormatString="{0:C}" on your column?

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="SomeValue" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
```

It will display the currency symbol according to the locale settings.

Answer (score 1):

As lcarus said, set the DataFormatString to "{0:C}" and it should work. However, and someone correct me if I am wrong, but it'll depend on the culture settings on the server. For example, if the culture setting on the server is "en-US", then you'll see a dollar sign. If I understand your post correctly, you're looking for the Pounds (GBP) symbol.

Now if your server is set for English UK, you're fine. But if its set to English US and you don't have the necessary access to change it, you can use a TemplateField.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MyColumn">
     <ItemTemplate>
          $<%# Eval("MyColumn")%>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I've used the dollar sign in that example, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

the Unicode Technical Committee accepted the proposed unicode code position ₹ (from the wikipedia) so you can change the your html to add these characters sequence.

Some one have done to show this symbol in his MVC WebGrid project. See here:

[how-to-show-indian-currency-symbol-in-mvc-webgrid](http://www.authorcode.com/how-to-show-indian-currency-symbol-in-mvc-webgrid/)

```
 grid1.Column("EmpName",format: (item) => new HtmlString("&#x20B9; " + Convert.ToString( item.Salary)), header: "Notes")))
```

i just want to say that we other ways to do so..so just try and share back..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this in three way, that i know

1. Programmatically,just override the culture

   {
   System,Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new       System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en:IN");
   }
2. It is possible to override page by page, on top of the page you want to override you can see the details of the page, like language,etc.
   There just add,

   `<%@ Page **Culture="en-IN"** Language = "C#".....>`
3. In web.config file, under configuration tag

   ```
     <System.Web>
          <Globalization Culture="en:IN"/>
     </System.Web>
   ```

That's It !!
We are done...:)

It is also possible to do it for each row in a gridview control by using RowDataBound event of that gridview control.

Thanks !!